# Auto growing input using a max width

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I want to auto grow text using an input. I have seen alot of tutorials using span and contenteditable, like for example:

```
      <span
        class="input"
        role="textbox"
        :data-placeholder="placeholder"
        contenteditable="true"
        @keyup="handleInput">
        {{ value }}
      </span>
```

But in my case I SPECIFICALLY want to use an input. my code looks like this right now and it works as intended, the only problem I am having is that I want to have a maximal width.

**MyComponent.vue**

```
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
      @keyup="handleInput"
      @blur="handleBlur" />
```

example of what it should do

so here I am calling my input component. and when I call it, I want to have the maximal width of the parent.

**example.vue**

```
//parent div gives the maximal width!
<div class="myInputClass">
  <my-input-component placeholder="Field Text Editor" value="this is a value">
  </my-input-component>
</div>
```

**styles**

```
.myInputClass {
width: 400px;
max-width: 400px
}
```

the max width is not working. how can I change my onInput, so it listens to the parent of my width. So it should stop growing when the width (in this example 400px) is achieved.

Also my focus looks like the first one: focus on the  first is using a span and the second one an input

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do set **max-width** css property in **MyComponent.vue**:

Like this below code :

```js
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    v-model="inputValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    oninput="this.size = this.value.length"
    @keyup="handleInput"
    @blur="handleBlur"
    style="max-width: 100%"
  />
</template>
```